# Display free disk space dynamically in the prompt

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

How can I dynamically display the free disk space left on a drive in my prompt? With dynamically I mean every time the prompt is regenerated after running a command it updates the free disk space left.

So far I tried this but for some reason it doesn't update.

`PS1="$PS1[free: $(df -h / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')] "`

Answer (score 2):

I forgot that I have to escape the `$` sign... This is the code now:

`PS1="$PS1[free: \$(df -h / | tail -1 | awk '{print \$4}')] "`

Comment: I suggest to add df‘s option `-P` for the case that the output is two-line.

Comment: And inline the `tail` into `awk` to reduce the load of this, since it's going to run a lot of times.  `df -Ph / | awk '{ n = $4 } END { print n }'` with the backslash before the `$4` if you put that in a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PROMPT_COMMAND environment variable.

This bash environment variable can execute commands each time the ENTER key is pressed.

export PROMPT_COMMAND="FREESP="$(df -h | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}')""

export PS1="PS1[free: $FREESP]"